# Silverlight app will not run in IE, but runs fine in Chrome/Firefox

Tags: silverlight

I have developed a silverlight 3 application using Sockets
connecting to a socket server hosted on the same host.

The application runs fine in both Chrome and Firefox on multiple computers
but in IE9 (Also in IE 7/8 compatible mode) the app just say: 100% (with the blue silverlight loader).

It never finishes loading and never starts up.

I have tried compiling the app in both Debug/Release mode without any result.

IE console say:

```
SCRIPT575: This method cannot be called until the send method has been called.
jquery-1.4.4.min.js?v=22, line 515 character 302
SCRIPT5022: Unhandled Error in Silverlight Application The given key was not present in the dictionary.   at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowKeyNotFoundException()
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at AppLaunch.Bloc.Frontend.SilverLight.UserOnlineClient.App.Application_Startup(Object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
   at MS.Internal.CoreInvokeHandler.InvokeEventHandler(Int32 typeIndex, Delegate handlerDelegate, Object sender, Object args)
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName)
```

Comment: Deleted answer as it doesn't apply in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer my own question.

The problem is with sending InitParams to the silverlight object with HTML. This works for all browsers except IE for some reason.

Pass parameters to silverlight apps by fetching them from the DOM tree instead.

Comment: Could you elaborate? I have not had issues with setting InitParams in IE.